# SQL find values that starts with a string

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

So, i have an online website.. and administrators have a name [ADM]Name. I want to block users to register with name of [ADM].

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE ']%'
```

Is this query good to select users who wish to make name with adm name ?

Note: I don't want to specify ADM, i want just  [  ] tags

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Post some sample user names and which you need to be excluded, if the given answers doesn't suit you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE '[ADM]%'
```

Comment: i don't want to specifi ADM, i want  [  ] patter i have more users with more grades

Comment: Then Just use '%[%'

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can do:

```
where name like '[%]%'
```

or if you specifically want "ADM":

```
where name like '[ADM]%'
```

Some databases extend like patterns, but MySQL is not one of them.